# Request parameter appended to URL twice in express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, internationalization, handlebars.js

Relevant lines from app.js:

```
var contact = require('./routes/contact');

app.all('/:lang/*', function(req, res, next){
  var selectedLang = req.params.lang;
  i18n.setLocale([req, res.locals], selectedLang);
  res.locals.language = selectedLang;
  next();
});

app.use('/contact', contact);
app.use('/:lang/contact', contact);
```

Menu link from nav.hbs:

```
<li><a href="{{language}}/contact">{{{__ "Kapcsolat"}}}</a></li>
```

Output that I get:

`http://127.0.0.1:3000/en/en/contact`

Expected output:

`http://127.0.0.1:3000/en/contact`

What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your nav.hbs to use this instead for your menu links:

```
<li><a href="/{{language}}/contact">{{{__ "Kapcsolat"}}}</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank You! This was it! I added this in app.js instead with `res.locals.language = '/' + selectedLang;`, because sometimes the url is just `http://127.0.0.1:3000/contact` (with default language in use).